# Ссылки на страницу из картинки в react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Как реализовать в React native, что бы при нажатии на определенную область картинки приложении переходило на следующий экран.
Например при нажатии на красную область открывалось бы экран пояснения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так и в обработчике проверяй координаты тапа с координатами красного блока, их надо рассчитать заранее:

```
handlePress = (evt) => {
  console.log(`x coord = ${evt.nativeEvent.locationX}, y coord =${evt.nativeEvent.locationY}`);
}


<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress}>
  <Image source={require('./back1.jpg')} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```